# How to limit the vertical spacing in itemize (enumerate) command

Tags: enumerate, itemize

[image]
When I use the enumerate command to to itemize it creates a 2/3line vertical space between two following items. 
How to **reduce this spacing** between items???

Sample Code : 
Journals:
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item M.M. Rahman, \textbf{M. Shuvo}, R. H. Kabir, Khan Md. Rabbi, \enquote{Heat transfer augmentation in a diamond shaped enclosure utilizing CNT-water Nanofluid}. [In Progress]\
\item \textbf{M. Shuvo}, R. H. Kabir, T. H. Pial, O. Bhowmik, Amin A. A., \enquote{Mode-I failure investigation of Eccentric circular and elliptical crack under uni-axial and bi-axial loading condition}.[In Progress]\vfill
\end{enumerate}

Comment: Using the `enumitem` package, you can set `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt]` or even `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-\parsep]`

Comment: Can you help me with the code when I want to use \begin {enumerate}..... \item.... \item \end{enumerate}

Comment: @user8097977 you might rather want to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we could improve. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @ebo I am new to this website and community, I will remember that in future. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Here is my code although i have edited my code with 'nosep' still there is fare amount of spacing :( i have attached a screenshot and also my code. Can you see what i did wrong ?

Comment: @MoinuddinShuvo Don't worry, it's normal: you're new... and welcomed! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The macro controlling the gap between items is `\itemsep`, which can be controlled with the `enumitem` package conveniently.  Also, `\parsep` controls vertical space between paragraphs *within* an item and can also be specified in this manner.

If the leading space is also an issue, `topsep` is the identifier.

See Appendix C.5.3 of Leslie Lamport's LaTeX User Guide and Reference Manual for details on what variables go into a list.

Gustavo rightly suggests using the logical declarations, `noitemsep` and `nosep` in lieu of actually specifying the values for `\itemsep`, `\parsep`, and `\topsep`.  I have added those into my MWE, while retaining the commented equivalent.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent Inter text
\begin{enumerate}
  \item blah
  \item blah blah
 \item blah blah blah
  \item blah blah blah blah
\end{enumerate}
Inter text
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt]
  \item blah
  \item blah blah
 \item blah blah blah
  \item blah blah blah blah
\end{enumerate}
Inter text
%\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]% IS THE SAME AS
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
  \item blah
  \item blah blah
 \item blah blah blah
  \item blah blah blah blah
\end{enumerate}
Inter text
%\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]% IS THE SAME AS
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \item blah
  \item blah blah
 \item blah blah blah
  \item blah blah blah blah
\end{enumerate}
Inter text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with the code when I want to use \begin {enumerate}..... \item.... \item \end{enumerate}

Comment: @user8097977 With the `enumitem` package, the same rules apply to `enumerate` as with `itemize`.  Note that `enumitem` = `enum`erate + `item`ize.

Comment: @user8097977 I have changed my example to `enumerate`.

Comment: May I suggest using the `noitemsep`/`nosep` keys as a higher-level solution, more oriented toward logical markup?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks for the clarifying edit!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Please can you elaborate?

Comment: @user8097977 Please look at the revised code in my answer.

Comment: @user8097977: Er… elaborate on what, precisely?  It seems to me that Steven’s updated answer already contains all necessary explanations.